# How to update nested object in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB schema sample below:

```json
{
 obj :  {
                 "count" : 3,
                 "id" : [ "X123", "X234", "X233"]
             }
}
```

New Id : ["X007"]

Now I need to update obj attribute by incrementing count & update new item in list. How to update it in single query ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UpdateItem` command with proper `UpdateExpression`, i.e. it should use `SET` and `list_append` to modify collection and `ADD` or `SET` to increment count.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.UpdatingListElements

Comment: As per the above documentation 


"Use the SET action in an update expression to add one or more attributes to an item. If any of these attributes already exists, they are overwritten by the new values."

In order to achieve this I need to know the value of list before final update

Comment: It will override only if you do not use `list_append`. You should merge old list and new item, something like `SET #my_list_attr=list_append(#my_list_attr, :new_item)`